# How to find age greater than value from json using pyspark?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new in pyspark. Can you please help me how to get max age from json using pyspark?
I tried `df.filter(df['employees.age'] > 22).show()`
It throws error,

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   '(`employees`.`age` > 22)' due to data type mismatch: differing types
>   in '(`employees`.`age` > 22)' (array and int).;; 'Filter
>   (employees#0.age > 22)

```
{'employees': [{'age': '12', 'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe'},
  {'age': '14', 'firstName': 'Anna', 'lastName': 'Smith'},
  {'age': '54', 'firstName': 'Peter1', 'lastName': 'Jones1'},
  {'age': '44', 'firstName': 'Peter2', 'lastName': 'Jones2'},
  {'age': '42', 'firstName': 'Peter3', 'lastName': 'Jones3'},
  {'age': '62', 'firstName': 'Peter4', 'lastName': 'Jones4'},
  {'age': '65', 'firstName': 'Peter5', 'lastName': 'Jones5'},
  {'age': '23', 'firstName': 'Peter6', 'lastName': 'Jones6'},
  {'age': '77', 'firstName': 'Pete7', 'lastName': 'Jones7'},
  {'age': '82', 'firstName': 'Peter8', 'lastName': 'Jones8'},
  {'age': '92', 'firstName': 'Peter9', 'lastName': 'Jones9'},
  {'age': '78', 'firstName': 'Peter10', 'lastName': 'Jones10'}]}
```

I want to find those employee who has age greater than 22.

Comment: Why would a filter operation give you a max?

Comment: is there any other method to get max value ?

Comment: Other than that, your query isn't wrong. The age is actually in  an array, Please [edit] your question to include the JSON.

Comment: Yeah. There's actually a `max(col)` function

Comment: I am new in Pyspark and I don't know.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/sql/basic.py    See in this file df.filter(df['employees.age'] > 22).show()

Comment: just copy paste the output of `df.show(5, truncate=False)` and `df.printSchema()` and update the question

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.max

Comment: Yeah. I see it. And that's not finding a max. It's removing anything less than 22. We can't accurately help you if you don't [edit] your question to include the JSON data

Comment: Sorry I want to find  those employee who have age greater 22

Comment: Can you paste what @RameshMaharjan asked please ?

Comment: [[12, John, Doe], [14, Anna, Smith], [54, Peter1, Jones1], [44, Peter2, Jones2], [42, Peter3, Jones3], [62, Peter4, Jones4], [65, Peter5, Jones5], [23, Peter6, Jones6], [77, Pete7, Jones7], [82, Peter8, Jones8], [92, Peter9, Jones9], [78, Peter10, Jones10]]|
root
 |-- employees: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)

Comment: so no one but me want to close this question ?

Comment: I second the CV. @PrashantPatel please read [ask] and [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples). We really do want to help, but it's hard to do without a [mcve].

Comment: how are you reading the json file?

Comment: @ Prashant Patel if u r in starting phase then plz read this url http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations

Comment: I will go through thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark doesn't handle multiple line data very well.

The Example code you linked to [shows how to need to lay out the file in the examples folder.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/resources/people.json)

Single objects on multiple lines. Not one object with an array

```
{'age': '54', 'firstName': 'Peter1', 'lastName': 'Jones1'}
{'age': '44', 'firstName': 'Peter2', 'lastName': 'Jones2'}
{'age': '42', 'firstName': 'Peter3', 'lastName': 'Jones3'}
```

Also, JSON uses double quotes for keys and values, so you'll need to fix that

Then

```
df = spark.read().json("file.json")
```

And, to find the max age

```
df.groupBy().max("age").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like You have a `list` (or `array`) in `employees.age`.
Even if you have only 1 item in that `array`.
Try use that in your code

```
"filter(employees#0.age > 22)"
```